# Importing Libraries Issue - "ImportError: No Module named ____"

Tags: python, numpy, libraries, pip, nltk

I've looked through a lot of the other question/answers for this topic but no avail.

I downloaded numpy and nltk using pip, and based on the messages I know the install location is:
    `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): nltk in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, so it looks like it's installing in the directory for version 2.7.

When I run `python` I get `Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43)`, so that's clearly also version 2.7.

However, when I try "import nltk" or "import numpy" in the Python console, I always get the `ImportError: No module named nltk` error. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It seems you have multiple python installations, and `nltk` is installed in "the other python." Changing `PYTHONPATH` is an ugly trick. Take a look at this answer and see if that's your situation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12206868/565999

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try changing the `PYTHONPATH`environment variable. If you are using BASH the below should work. Other Linux shells will be slightly different in how they assign environment variables.

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Comment: I had to export the .../dist-packages to make nltk and some other packages accessible via python terminal. Thanks for this hint.

Comment: changing the PYTHONPATH also worked python34 C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages  (the path was shown in the list given by  import sys
for pth in sys.path:print pth but somehow it did not work until I edited the pythonpath

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` is not in your default path list. In order to verify this, run the following commands:

```
import sys
for pth in sys.path:
    print pth
```

You will get a list of the directories searched for modules. As you probably will not have `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` in the list, you have the following options:

1. Remove `nltk` and install it again in one of the directories paths (note, that e.g. on Debian, it may be `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`.
2. On each run, set PYTHONPATH variable: `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` (you can put this command in the `$HOME/.bashrc` file).
3. Put a file `local.pth` in `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages` or `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` (depending on the output of the script above), which contains a single line:

   ```
   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
   ```

   This will add this directory to your default path list permanently.
4. (This one is recommended only for some seldom-used non-standard packages installed in some strange location, which is probably not your case) In the beginning of your script (before `import nltk`) add the following code:

   ```
   import sys
   sys.path.append("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")
   ```