# ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl

I am trying to use the betbrain.py from Github (https://github.com/gto76/betbrain-scraper) that has the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#
# Usage: betbrain.py [URL or FILE] [OUTPUT-FILE]
# Scrapes odds from passed betbrain page and writes them to
# stdout, or file if specified.

import os
import sys
import urllib.request


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from http.cookiejar import CookieJar

import parser_betbrain
import printer

DEFAULT_URL = 'https://www.betbrain.com/football/england/premier-league/#!/matches/'


# If no arguments are present, it parses the default page.
# Argument can be an URL or a local file.
def main():
  html = getHtml(sys.argv)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
  matches = parser_betbrain.getMatches(soup)
  string = printer.matchesToString(matches)
  output(string, sys.argv)

def getHtml(argv):
  if len(argv) <= 1:
    return scrape(DEFAULT_URL)
  elif argv[1].startswith("http"):
    return scrape(argv[1])
  else:
    return readFile(argv[1])

# Returns html file located at URL.
def scrape(url):
  cj = CookieJar()
  opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
  try:
    return opener.open(url)
  except ValueError:
    error("Invalid URL: " + url)

def readFile(path):
  try:
    return open(path, encoding='utf8')
  except IOError:
    error("Invalid input filename: " + path)

def output(string, argv):
  if len(argv) <= 2:
    print(string)
  else:
    writeFile(argv[2], string)

def writeFile(path, string):
  try:  
    fo = open(path, "w", encoding='utf8')
    fo.write(string);
    fo.close()
  except IOError:
    error("Invalid output filename: " + path)

def error(msg):
  msg = os.path.basename(__file__)+": "+msg
  print(msg, file=sys.stderr)
  sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

**However when run it comes back with this error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1318, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1400, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 401, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 808, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1061, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 683, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Daniel/Desktop/betbrain-scraper-master 2/betbrain.py", line 71, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/Daniel/Desktop/betbrain-scraper-master 2/betbrain.py", line 22, in main
    html = getHtml(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/Daniel/Desktop/betbrain-scraper-master 2/betbrain.py", line 30, in getHtml
    return scrape(DEFAULT_URL)
  File "/Users/Daniel/Desktop/betbrain-scraper-master 2/betbrain.py", line 41, in scrape
    return opener.open(url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1361, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1320, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)>
```

**How can I fix this problem? I am running Python 3.6.0 on MacOS 10.12.1**

Answer (score 214):

Open a terminal and take a look at:

```
/Applications/Python 3.6/Install Certificates.command
```

Python 3.6 on MacOS uses an embedded version of OpenSSL, which does not use the system certificate store. More details [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue28150).

(To be explicit: MacOS users can probably resolve by opening Finder and double clicking [Install Certificates.command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWgpe.png))

Comment: This command fixed another one problem that described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38835270/i-get-certificate-verify-failed-when-i-try-to-install-the-spacy-english-language

Comment: I do have the same problem with py36 that was installed using pyenv so this command does not exist. Also, I was able to replicate the same error with python 2.7

Comment: Is there a solution, if one doesn't have root access? I did `pip3 install --user certifi`, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: This approach helped me fix another vexing problem: https://github.com/fangli/django-saml2-auth/issues/24. Its strange that the default installer didnt install this command since it seems it breaks a few other python3.6 programs (canto the rss reader) in a similarly non-obvious way.

Comment: Worked for me. But not doing via double clicking gave `Permision Denied`
What I did was
`cd Applications/Python\ 3.6`
And then
`sudo ./Install\ Certificates.command `
This worked for me

Comment: For those without root; check out this answer: https://bugs.python.org/issue29095

Comment: Really wish I'd seen this last time I had this issue... Thanks being specific about the path (although granted should have been a no brainer) was super helpful.

Comment: It's the same problem if you're using python 2.6 also. We need to run Certificates.command

Comment: If you want avoid ssl verification set the environment variable PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY to 0.

- By typing linux command:
```
export PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY = 0
```
OR
- Using in python code:
```
import os
os.environ["PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY"] = "0"
```

Answer (score 39):

I ran this on MacOS `/Applications/Python\ 3.6/Install\ Certificates.command`

Comment: You're awesome bro.

Answer (score 8):

In windows adding these 2 lines on the top can be a quick fix:

```
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

Answer (score 3):

On CentOS Linux, Python3.6, I edited this file (make a backup copy first)

```
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem
```

to the end of the file, I added my public certificate from my .pem file.
you should be able to obtain the .pem file from your ssl certificate provider.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the same issue in the official Python docker and solved it by running `apt-get update && apt-get install ca-certificates` before running any of the `nltk` code.

Comment: After fiddling with my situation, the problem was related to `ca-certificates`. I updated this package and all is well.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all other solutions but no luck until this. This may not a silver bullet but yet worth a try. Good luck.

```py
import ssl
import urllib.request

context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
context.check_hostname = False
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(
    urllib.request.HTTPSHandler(context=ssl_context),
    urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj),
)
```

Comment: This should be fine when you don't really care about verifying the certificate, ignoring any risk of man-in-the-middle attacks (for sending non-sensitive info).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I fixed it:

1. Opened the Install Cerificates.Command.The shell script got executed.
2. Opened the Python 3.6.5 and typed in `nltk.download()`.The download graphic window opened and all the packages got installed.