# issue installing english model in Spacy for Python3

Tags: python, python-3.6, spacy

(Mac os X 10.12.2)

So, when I run these 2 lines:

```
pip install spacy
python -m spacy.en.download all
```

it's working perfectly and I can use spacy with the english model in python (2.x)

but when I run the same for python3 (3.6.0)

```
pip3 install spacy
python3 -m spacy.en.download all
```

it installs spacy but I got errors when downloading the model. So when I then use spacy in python3 it doesn't work, I got empty fields instead of pos, tag ...

the errors I get are related to the urllib:

```
Downloading parsing model
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1318, in do_open
encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
self.connect()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1400, in connect
server_hostname=server_hostname)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 401, in wrap_socket
_context=self, _session=session)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 808, in __init__
self.do_handshake()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1061, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 683, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/en/download.py", line 25, in <module>
plac.call(main)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plac_core.py", line 328, in call
cmd, result = parser.consume(arglist)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plac_core.py", line 207, in consume
return cmd, self.func(*(args + varargs + extraopts), **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/en/download.py", line 18, in main
download('en', force=False, data_path=data_path)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/download.py", line 36, in download
about.__models__.get(lang, lang), data_path)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sputnik/__init__.py", line 37, in install
index.update()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sputnik/index.py", line 84, in update
index = json.load(session.open(request, 'utf8'))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sputnik/session.py", line 43, in open
r = self.opener.open(request)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
'_open', req)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1361, in https_open
context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1320, in do_open
raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)>
```

Any ideas on what to do?

thanks a lot!
cheers

EDIT: I've asked the question on the spacy repository on Github as well and apparently the only way is to copy/paste the data from python2.7 to python3.6:

so I've copy/paste the folder `en-1.1.0`
from `/Users/[myname]/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spacy/data`
to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/data/`

and everything works fine, can use Spacy in python3 now!

hope it will help others

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm new to Stackoverflow I'm not able to comment or flag this question as a possible duplicate…
So as a "normal" answer: As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41691327/ssl-sslerror-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify-failed-ssl-c/41692664) answer it seems that there is a solution for Mac OS. Hope this helps!