# spacy POS, lemma

Tags: python, spacy

I think I am missing something, but I don't manage to get POS and lemma results even when I just try their example:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
doc = nlp(u'They told us to duck.')
for word in doc:
    print(word.text, word.lemma, word.lemma_, word.tag, word.tag_, word.pos, word.pos_)
```

I get:

```
(u'They', 0, u'', 0, u'', 0, u'')
(u'told', 0, u'', 0, u'', 0, u'')
(u'us', 0, u'', 0, u'', 0, u'')
(u'to', 0, u'', 0, u'', 0, u'')
(u'duck', 0, u'', 0, u'', 0, u'')
(u'.', 0, u'', 0, u'', 0, u'')
```

I am in 64bit python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the english model is not available. Did you download it as described [here] (https://spacy.io/docs/usage/)?

A note on the documented procedure:
There sometimes seem to be some ssl-related issues with downloading the model via terminal (for MacOS there is a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41691327/ssl-sslerror-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify-failed-ssl-c/41692664), unfortunately only for python3).

The good news is that it seems that they fixed it in that you are now able to download the models manually as described [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/507) (it's quite a long thread - scroll to the very bottom of it and look for the response by ines. At the time of writing it is the third last answer).

Hope this helps!