# While using pandas got error urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, ssl

This is my code in python3 :

```
import pandas as pd

tables = pd.read_html("http://http.com/")

print(tables)
```

And I got this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1318, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1400, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 401, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 808, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1061, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 683, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 906, in read_html
    keep_default_na=keep_default_na)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 743, in _parse
    raise_with_traceback(retained)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 344, in raise_with_traceback
    raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)>
```

This have been working very well till now, but I have this problem on this particular website. Also, I am new in this and don't know much about SSL Certificate, I searched it on google and still do not have much knowledge about it.

Answer (score 66):

use -

```py
import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

Comment: What is this black magic? It fixed my problem too.

Comment: This worked for me on windows, conda python 3.9.7. Pandas read_csv() was failing on a url and the above fixed it.

Comment: changed the error to `HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Errodeconfiguracaodobrowser`

Comment: how can i use ssl then to bypass verification?

Comment: good quick fix. It would have been better if there was some explanation

Answer (score 22):

For MAC
Click Applications => Python then double-click Install Certificates.command.

Comment: But there is no Python in Applications...can you tell where exactly in Applications. I assumed Finder => Applications.

Comment: See answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42098127/778533 and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41692664/778533.

Comment: very simple solution, specially after having found so many complex alternatives. Thank you very much!

Comment: for students answer by @markroxor is simple BUT for real life usage Mayank's answer IS THE RIGHT WAY

Comment: This should be the verified answer here. Thank you!