# <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)>

Tags: ssl-certificate

I did the manual installation on python 3.7.5 on Debian 8, when I will run the script I get this error:

```
<urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)>
```

I saw several questions here in the stackoverflow more regarding MacOS, In my case this error is in Linux.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue. Here is what I found helped my problem.

```
import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44629631/while-using-pandas-got-error-urlopen-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-cert) for the original answer from markroxor. Hope it will help your problem as well.

Answer (score 5):

What worked for my MacOs:

1. Open the finder
2. Find the version of Python that you are using
3. Open its folder
4. Click on the "Install Certificates.command". It will open a terminal and install the certificate.

[image]

Comment: thank you for sharing! that solved the issue on my new mac!

Answer (score 3):

I had

```
<urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)>
```

With python3 3.9.2-3, and other python related packages with the same, or similar, version. On Debian GNU/Linux 11 (Bullseye).

At first, using the suggested

```
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

managed to solve the problem. Though I do not know if, and which, down sides, or other side effects, this solution has.

Afterwards, I noticed the `/etc/ssl/certs/` folder is empty. Installing the `ca-certificates` package fills in this folder. Which seem to be another solution, in which those 2 python ssl lines are not required. You can see [here](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/all/ca-certificates/filelist) the detailed list of files the `ca-certificates` package installed. [This](https://www.happyassassin.net/posts/2015/01/12/a-note-about-ssltls-trusted-certificate-stores-and-platforms/) article, from 2015, with a last comment from 2017, discusses the location of ca-certificates in various OSs/distributions. I think the `ca-certificates` package is rather basic, and is usually installed as part of the initial installation of the machine. I do not know how it was missing from that particular machine.

Comment: solved for me in Mac

Answer (score 1):

In my case (Dell computer), the SSL problem was caused by Dell software itself:
[reported here](https://%20https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-Developer-Systems/Dell-Command-Configure-breaks-OpenSSL-and-other-things/td-p/8275666). In that case, according to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/718751/358112) to another question in the SE network, you can solve the problem by running the following command:

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3 /opt/dell/dcc/libcrypto.so.3
```

And then, run this:

```
sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh
```

It worked for me on a Dell Latitude 7310, LinuxMint21. November 2022.

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS NOT A SOLUTION:
I have encountered that several times, note however that i'm using windows, but i would assume that generally the resolving mehtods should be the same in principle for mac/linux.

What i used to do is to force it to not verify the certificate by using the below:

```
conda config --set ssl_verify false
```

Note this is not a solution to the issue, it's just a way to make the code run temporarily, or if you're trying to download a library then that should do the trick until you download it. Note that the suggested below is not usually recommended, if you do it, after running your code/ downloading your library, remember to turn it back on using the below:

```
conda config --set ssl_verify true
```

Answer (score 0):

If this happened after you installed a python version manually, inside the python app folder, double click on the "Install Certificates.command" file and it should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The source I found for the "Install Certificates" command is located here:
https://gist.github.com/marschhuynh/31c9375fc34a3e20c2d3b9eb8131d8f3

Add this as a new file to your python directory for future use if needed.  I called mine "Install Certificates.py".  Then I simply ran (double clicked) the file and it installed a certificate.  Now I have an https connection.  Hopefully this works for you.

(Adding this as new file is as easy as creating an empty .txt file and pasting the code in, then save it.  Finally change the extension to .py and double click the file to run it.)