# how do I web scrape a table with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This might not be the smartest question but I've spent about an hour trying to figure out and doing research ending up with nothing. As a last resort I am posting my problem here.

The website I am using is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Super_Bowl_halftime_shows and I want to scrape the tables listed under history.

When I inspect the page I see that it is under an anchor tag with specific titles
[image]

I do not mind scraping each table individually/manually but no matter how I try to navigate to the table with its respective anchor and title, my bs(beautifulsoup) object does not have any contents of the table.

I'm guessing the href attribute is used to display the table so my question is how can I scrape the contents of a webpage that is using another link that I do not have access to?

Comment: Do you want to scrape _all_  tables under "history"?

Comment: yes every single superbowl event

Comment: i see it is referencing a link to display the table. maybe im wrong. but i dont see how i can access the table because it seems the link that is used on wikipedia has to do with some local path/link for the user that posted it.

Comment: Do you have the pandas library installed?

Comment: yes i am using pandas for this project. u can assume i know the basics of data science with python

Comment: this is actually a "project" on the datacamp website but the problem with it is that it just offers up all the libraries/data and i want to do it all from scratch because i expect that is how it will be done realistically in a job setting or if i want to explore anything on my own so i am trying to do the websites project on my own instead of having my hand held all the way cus ill learn nothing

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `pandas` you can use `read_html()` to get all tables and access specific tables using indexing.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Super_Bowl_halftime_shows")
print(df[0].to_string()) # <-- Acess the first table
```

Comment: TypeError: cannot parse from 'Response'

Comment: How are you using `read_html`? pass it a URL as I do

Comment: URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1125)>

Comment: the first error was my mistake i did not use the url. but i litearlly copy and pasted your suggestion and i get this error

Comment: Don't use `urlopen`/`requests` use `pandas` directly

Comment: yes i used pandas directly and i get this url error

Comment: @GirthyLampost see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44629631/while-using-pandas-got-error-urlopen-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-cert

Comment: okay i imported ssl and made the context but how does that help?

Comment: first time ive seen ssl and im looking at the documentation for it but dont know how it applies to my error

Comment: @GirthyLampost isn't that the error you received?