# urllib.request.urlopen(url) NOT Working

Tags: python-3.6, urlopen

I am trying to read a simple stock page with the following code. The last line returns an error. I have double checked that the url works and have also tried multiple url's as a check. **Any help please?**

```
import urllib.request
url = "https://www.google.com"
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
```

Comment: What is the error you get ?

Comment: 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1318, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))

Comment: Below is the full error. It is quite lengthy but I'll post it if it can help.

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41691327/ssl-sslerror-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify-failed-ssl-c

Comment: Perfect! That worked.Thank you!

Comment: Welcome :) But please google before asking a question

Comment: Thank you. I will. I tried to find the answer to this for over an hour. No luck. I need to brush up on my google skills as well i guess....