# squeezenet1.1.caffemodel" is not existing file

Tags: python, neural-network, conv-neural-network, intel, openvino

I have installed all the required steps for openvino. but while running the demos, to make sure that every thing is working fine , I am recieving this error : **The "C:\Users\OGNGHAFF\Documents\Intel\OpenVINO\openvino_models\models\public\squeezenet1.1/squeezenet1.1.caffemodel" is not existing file**

I couldn't find any solution.

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\bin\
setupvars.bat
```

This is working fine. Then I am running initilazation:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\deployment_tools\model_optimizer\install_prerequisites
install_prerequisites.bat
```

This is also working fine, but then when I want to run demo :

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\deployment_tools\demo\
demo_squeezenet_download_convert_run.bat
```

I am recieving this error :

```
**Download public squeezenet1.1 model
python "C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\deployment_tools\open_model_zoo\tools\downloader\downloader.py" --name "squeezenet1.1" --output_dir "C:\Users\OGNGHAFF\Documents\Intel\OpenVINO\openvino_models\models" --cache_dir "C:\Users\OGNGHAFF\Documents\Intel\OpenVINO\openvino_models\cache"
################|| Downloading models ||################

========== Downloading C:\Users\OGNGHAFF\Documents\Intel\OpenVINO\openvino_models\models\public\squeezenet1.1\squeezenet1.1.prototxt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\OGNGHAFF\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\OGNGHAFF\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\OGNGHAFF\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 850, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\OGNGHAFF\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 326, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "C:\Users\OGNGHAFF\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 329, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\OGNGHAFF\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "C:\Users\OGNGHAFF\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\ssl.py", line 814, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\OGNGHAFF\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\ssl.py", line 1068, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\OGNGHAFF\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\OGNGHAFF\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\OGNGHAFF\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Users\OGNGHAFF\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 388, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='raw.githubusercontent.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /DeepScale/SqueezeNet/a47b6f13d30985279789d08053d37013d67d131b/SqueezeNet_v1.1/deploy.prototxt (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)'),))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\deployment_tools\open_model_zoo\tools\downloader\downloader.py", line 71, in try_download
    chunk_iterable = start_download()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\deployment_tools\open_model_zoo\tools\downloader\downloader.py", line 261, in <lambda>
    lambda: model_file.source.start_download(session, CHUNK_SIZE)):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\deployment_tools\open_model_zoo\tools\downloader\common.py", line 185, in start_download
    response = session.get(self.url, stream=True, timeout=DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT)
  File "C:\Users\OGNGHAFF\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 521, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\OGNGHAFF\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\OGNGHAFF\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\OGNGHAFF\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 506, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='raw.githubusercontent.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /DeepScale/SqueezeNet/a47b6f13d30985279789d08053d37013d67d131b/SqueezeNet_v1.1/deploy.prototxt (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)'),))
########## Error: Download failed**
```

Comment: You should include what command you ran as well. Most likely, the problem is with the path.

Comment: I added the code that I am running. thank you.

Comment: Your problem is related to SSL certificates. maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41691327/8243797) will help.

Comment: I am working on windows, and this solution is only for Mac.

Comment: I may guess  your computer is under a proxy server and it is blocking github servers. If this is the case the following command should help: python -m pip install --trusted-host raw.githubusercontent.com --upgrade pip

Answer (score -1):

As suggested in the comments above, make sure to configure your proxy settings for pip if you are behind a proxy server.

Try configuring your `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` variables as follows:

```
set http_proxy=http://[username:password@]proxyserver:port
set https_proxy=https://[username:password@]proxyserver:port
```