# Installing spaCy - SSL Certificate Error

Tags: python, ssl, spacy

I have installed spaCy using `pip install spacy` but when trying `python -m spacy.en.download all`, I get the following error ..

[image]

(For Google -- `ssl.CertificateError: hostname 'index.spacy.io` doesn't match 'api.explosion.ai'`)

Is there a way to fix this easily? Ref ..

- https://spacy.io/docs/usage/ - Installing spaCy
- [I get CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED when I try to install the spaCy English language model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38835270/i-get-certificate-verify-failed-when-i-try-to-install-the-spacy-english-language)
- https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/507 - GitHub issue related

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the new version in Linux. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind a proxy? I have to set ssl to false and then back again once installed.
`config conda --set ssl_verify false` in anaconda prompt might work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Disconnecting from VPN(Virtual Private Network) worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50507111/4341458) answer, I am on MacOS and was not behind a proxy. The below command installing from source got around the error.

```
pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-3.0.0/en_core_web_sm-3.0.0.tar.gz
```

Answer (score -1):

This error is fixed in the latest spacy version and should not occur anymore. If you are experiencing the issue you should

1. update your spacy version using `pip install -U spacy`
2. and install the new models using `python -m spacy download en`

Be aware that the download command changed for installing models!

Comment: when the above commands are used there ssl error appears is there a way to do ssl_verify_false for the command like `python -m spacy download en`? I need to do: `python -m spacy download en_trf_bertbaseuncased_lg`