# unable to download spacy model

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, python-3.6, spacy

Downloading spacy "en" model by following command

```
python -m spacy download en
```

throws URL error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/siddharthdas/venvs/chai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/__main__.py", line 31, in <module>
    plac.call(commands[command], sys.argv[1:])
  File "/Users/siddharthdas/venvs/chai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plac_core.py", line 328, in call
    cmd, result = parser.consume(arglist)
  File "/Users/siddharthdas/venvs/chai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plac_core.py", line 207, in consume
    return cmd, self.func(*(args + varargs + extraopts), **kwargs)
  File "/Users/siddharthdas/venvs/chai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/cli/download.py", line 30, in download
    shortcuts = get_json(about.__shortcuts__, "available shortcuts")
  File "/Users/siddharthdas/venvs/chai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/cli/download.py", line 55, in get_json
    data = url_read(url)
  File "/Users/siddharthdas/venvs/chai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/compat.py", line 82, in url_read
    file_ = url_open(url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1361, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1320, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)>
```

Then I tried installing `Install Certificates.command` but it didn't solved the problem.

**Specifications**:

OS: Mac High Sierra

ENV: venv (python virtual environment)

Comment: Did you install as an administrator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem might be related to [this issue and PR](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/pull/2212#issuecomment-386357643), and the fact that unlike `requests`, `urllib` doesn't check for certificates in extra places.

After some back and forth, the upcoming version of spaCy will revert this change and go back to using `requests` – dropping the dependency just wasn't worth the hassle. In the meantime, you can always download and install the models manually by pointing `pip install` to the direct URL. [See this section](https://spacy.io/usage/models#download-pip) in the docs for details.