# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error while downloading python -m spacy download en

Tags: spacy

I have downloaded spacy in Anaconda prompt by using conda install -c conda-forge spacy. But when I tried to download en_core_we_sm using python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm I getting SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error.
[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install fails with "connection error: \[SSL: CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED\] certificate verify failed (\_ssl.c:598)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi)

Comment: No both have different error codes. Mine is (_ssl.c:1056) while the one in the other question is (_ssl.c:598)

Comment: That's just different line numbers -- it's normal for them to change between different versions of the library; it's still the same underlying problem, with the same solutions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I get CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED when I try to install the spaCy English language model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38835270/i-get-certificate-verify-failed-when-i-try-to-install-the-spacy-english-language)

Answer (score 36):

With HTTPS, trying to download something from a remote host produces an SSL connection error in some cases like if your computer is behind a proxy which does not let you to make SSL connection freely. For those cases, a downloading manager like pip , conda for python or apt-get or yum for Linux provide some options for a user to specify certificate for such connections or to allow untrusted communication with a remote host for such downloads.

However, downloading a model VIA spacy with `python -m spacy download` does not provide such options. You cannot add any SSL certificates nor specify trusted host for a download.

Fortunately, there's a workaround solution with two separate steps , downloading and installing. That is, download the model with any other clients which is under control with SSL (browser, curl, wget...) then install the downloaded model with `pip install`

Find appropriate model you need on https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases and download tar.gz file like,

`wget https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5.tar.gz`

Then install it like,

`python -m pip install ./en_core_web_sm-2.2.5.tar.gz`

Comment: Thanks for this. why is this not an accepted answer!

Comment: I got most of the answers nearly after a year of posting this question. By the time I probably skipped this question. And right now I don't recall what I was working on and so can not verify it. If there are many up ticks for the answer then the answer should probably work. Sorry about that!

Comment: I have had the same issue and this answer has worked for me!

Comment: This command helpfully  tells you the url of *which* model to download (taken from  https://spacy.io/usage/models#download-pip): `spacy info en_core_web_sm --url`. You can then simply download the model's whl file using your web browser.

Answer (score 5):

The answer provided by K. Symbol is helpful. As an alternative, the download and installation can be done in one statement with pip. Pip can be assigned "trusted-host" and the "install" object can be a website, so:

```
pip --trusted-host github.com --trusted-host objects.githubusercontent.com install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_md-3.4.0/en_core_web_md-3.4.0.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 4):

Just download the direct version.

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm-2.2.0 --direct
```

I had the same error as you, gave this a try, and it worked. For more information here are some additional details from the model page:
https://spacy.io/usage/models

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was i was running the command "python -m spacy download en" from a  different location other than "C:\WINDOWS\system32". When i ran the command from "C:\WINDOWS\system32" with "Run as Admin" it worked like charm. Seems from other locations it is not able to load the correct ssl config.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to download it because you cannot verify the certificate as you are behind a company proxy, you can also do the following by first downloading the file via requests and specifying that you don't want to check certifictates, then install it via pip:

```py
import requests, os

lang = 'en'
r = requests.get(f'https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/{lang}_core_news_sm-3.0.0/{lang}_core_news_sm-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl',
                 verify=False)  # verify=False to skip checking of certificate
file = f'{lang}_core_news_sm-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl'
with open(file,'wb') as output_file:
    output_file.write(r.content)  # save the wheel locally
# then install it via pip
!pip install {file} --user  
os.remove(file)  # remove the file
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a virtual environment:

First, add the certificates in your local chain,
usually located at:

```
your_folder\venv\Lib\site-packages\certifi\cacert.pem
```

In Windows concatenate using:

```
type your_cer.cer >> your_folder\venv\Lib\site-packages\certifi\cacert.pem
```

Try download manually:

```
python -m spacy download pt_core_news_lg-3.5.0 --direct --use-feature=truststore
```

To install packages use:

```
pip install yourpackage --use-feature=truststore
```

Answer (score -2):

First, Uninstall Spacy and clean the directories. Then install with the following link -

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org spacy
```

Use pip3 for Python3 and run following in a terminal

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

let me know if you still get error/s. Follow https://spacy.io/usage/models

Comment: This cannot be a solution as the problem caused by disabled SSL connection while downloading spacy model where a user cannot let the download command to trust any host with or without a specific certificates. Reinstalling with the "trusted-host" option does not affect any following SSL requests made after the installation. Also, the link describes nothing about a solution to this problem.

Comment: Basically that solution worked for me, also trusted host is from pypi.org from where the library will get downloaded.

Comment: @NaitikChandak, if you don't force ssl certificates to be validated, how do you know it's _really_ pypi.org that the download is coming from? Could be some hacker who took over your coffeeshop wifi and is substituting their own code with a bitcoin miner added to the library you want.