# SSL Certificate error while installing Spacy

Tags: spacy, rasa, rasa-x

I am facing the below error while installing Spacy.

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='raw.githubusercontent.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /explosion/spacy-models/master/compatibility.json (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')))
```

**Command i'm running :** python -m spacy download en_core_web_md

Comment: Hello, I'm a spaCy dev. We've had reports of errors like that before but it's always been an issue with user Internet connections. Maybe you're on a corporate intranet or an unreliable connection or something?

Comment: Hey, thanks for response. Yes i'm on a corporate network. Could you please help me fixing it.

Comment: Unfortunately we can't do anything about it because there's nothing wrong on our end, you'll have to ask your IT department for help.

Comment: Actually, it might be an issue with your Python being old or something, try the instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55742788/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error-while-downloading-python-m-spacy-download

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I get CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED when I try to install the spaCy English language model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38835270/i-get-certificate-verify-failed-when-i-try-to-install-the-spacy-english-language)

Answer (score 6):

I have fixed using this set of commands:

```
pip install pip-system-certs
python -m spacy download it_core_news_sm
```

Ref: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/5649

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by following the below steps.

```
Edited the .condarc file with ssl = false
while installing the anaconda, the default checkbox for PATH setup leave as it is.
```

Thanks