# Could not install spaCy language model behind proxy, got error SSL: Certificate_Verify_Failed

Tags: python, pip, conda, spacy

I'm trying to install en_core_web_sm on my company computer (Windows 10) which has proxy firewall. I've tried downloading the package and install from local directory using conda terminal command:

`python -m pip install ./en_core_web_sm-3.0.0.tar.gz`

which is an answer from this post: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error while downloading python -m spacy download en](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55742788/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error-while-downloading-python-m-spacy-download/55793897#55793897)

But I still get the same error on SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED. My question is why is SSL still being checked when installing from local folder.

In addition, is there a direct way to simply load the downloaded language model package? I've unzip the files and save in my working directory, and I wrote this in my python code:

`nlp = spacy.load("/en_core_web_sm-3.0.0/")`

This also didn't work. Got an error about Can't find the model 'en/core_web_sm-3.0.0'.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can [download the .whl or .gz file directly and install from a local path](https://spacy.io/usage/models#download-pip). Note that since SpaCy models technically are python packages you need to **install it with pip from the local file** and afterwards load it normally in your python code.

For your model [this file](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/tag/en_core_web_sm-3.2.0) is the more current one which is probably better to use than version 3.0.0.