# Mayavi and VTK on Apple M1?

Tags: python, visualization, vtk, mayavi, apple-silicon

I'm trying to install Mayavi for visualizations on my M1 Air. Mayavi has a dependency on VTK - which does not have official binaries for Apple Silicon yet. I tried compiling it from source and updated the paths, but when I do `pip install mayavi`, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vtk'`.

Have you had any success?

Comment: Hello, try like this `brew install vtk` and then `pip install mayavi` you have to have homebrew installed though.

Comment: Thank you. That is the first thing I tried; still get the same error.

Comment: According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182052/installing-mayavi-with-pip-no-module-named-vtk) maybe pip is using another version of python for the venv.

Comment: According to [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/issues/18158#note_925881) apple M1 is not offically supported by VTK ...

Answer (score 0):

[Surfice](https://www.nitrc.org/plugins/mwiki/index.php/surfice:MainPage) can view many mesh-based formats (including VTK), while [MRIcroGL](https://www.nitrc.org/plugins/mwiki/index.php/mricrogl:MainPage) can support many voxel-based formats (including VTK). They are open source and compiled natively for macOS, Linux and Windows. The macOS builds are universal (native x86-64 and Apple Silicon). The programs allow Python scripting (the Scripting menus provide a lot of sample scripts that demonstrate the capability). This may help fill the gap until VTK fully supports the M1.

Answer (score 0):

There are some tricks that you can use vtk(pyvtk) pkg in m1 silicon, here are tutorials:
1.have a x86 macbook
2.build vtk environment using homebrew(you can add pyqt et.al)
3.using your new m1 to mirror copy x64 macbook
4.build an environment in your /usr/local/your_python_path
5.enjoy vtk for m1!